# Search JSON with Python - Count Cars Count People

Tags: python, json

I am very new to Python and I am looking for advice on how to extract data from the JSON file below.

I would like a Python script that does the following

Find Label "Car" if confidence is >90 then count "BoundingBox" and output "The are x Cars"
else output "there are no Cars".

Find Label "Person" if confidence is >85 then count "BoundingBox" and output "The are x People"
else output "there are no People".

Would you use the "import json"

import json

I appreciate any help you can provide on this

```
{
    "Labels": [{
            "Name": "Car",
            "Confidence": 97.12930297851562,
            "Instances": [{
                    "BoundingBox": {
                        "Width": 0.3040655553340912
                    },
                    "Confidence": 97.12930297851562
                },
                {
                    "BoundingBox": {
                        "Width": 0.21719124913215637
                    },
                    "Confidence": 87.27943420410156
                },
                {
                    "BoundingBox": {
                        "Width": 0.1468130648136139
                    },
                    "Confidence": 63.32168960571289
                }
            ],
            "Parents": [{
                    "Name": "Vehicle"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Transportation"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Automobile",
            "Confidence": 97.12930297851562,
            "Instances": [],
            "Parents": [{
                    "Name": "Vehicle"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Transportation"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Person",
            "Confidence": 85.63351440429688,
            "Instances": [{
                "BoundingBox": {
                    "Width": 0.024131836369633675
                },
                "Confidence": 85.63351440429688
            }],
            "Parents": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Freeway",
            "Confidence": 55.29652786254883,
            "Instances": [],
            "Parents": [{
                "Name": "Road"
            }]
        }
    ],
    "LabelModelVersion": "2.0"
}
```

Comment: You use `json.loads()` to convert the JSON to dictionaries and lists. Then you just use ordinary Python operations to loop over the data and count what you want.

Comment: Thanks - this helped a lot. I managed to come up with something that works , I have posted it below. If you can see any way of optimizing it then I would appreciate your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Barmar

Thanks - I used your advice and came up with this python script. I still need to work out how to strip off the outer JSON lables
{"Labels":[
]}],"LabelModelVersion":"2.0"}

This script will be used to take response from Amazon AWS Rekognition and people and car count.

```
import json

#### Import Data from Analysis service ####

print ('### Raw JSON file from analysis ###')

z = {"Labels":[{"Name":"Car","Confidence":97.12930297851562,"Instances": 
[{"BoundingBox": 
{"Width":0.3040655553340912},"Confidence":97.12930297851562}, 
{"BoundingBox": 
{"Width":0.21719124913215637},"Confidence":87.27943420410156}, 
{"BoundingBox": 
{"Width":0.1468130648136139},"Confidence":63.32168960571289}],"Parents": 
[{"Name":"Vehicle"},{"Name":"Transportation"}]}, 
{"Name":"Automobile","Confidence":97.12930297851562,"Instances": 
[],"Parents":[{"Name":"Vehicle"},{"Name":"Transportation"}]}, 
{"Name":"Person","Confidence":85.63351440429688,"Instances": 
[{"BoundingBox": 
{"Width":0.024131836369633675},"Confidence":85.63351440429688}],"Parents": 
[]},{"Name":"Freeway","Confidence":55.29652786254883,"Instances": 
[],"Parents":[{"Name":"Road"}]}],"LabelModelVersion":"2.0"}

# convert into JSON:
w = json.dumps(z)

#### Need to find a procedure to remove the outer {"Labels": 
[],"LabelModelVersion":"2.0"}

print ('### JSON file with outer label removed ###')

x = {"Name":"Car","Confidence":97.12930297851562,"Instances": 
[{"BoundingBox": 
{"Width":0.3040655553340912},"Confidence":97.12930297851562}, 
{"BoundingBox": 
{"Width":0.21719124913215637},"Confidence":87.27943420410156}, 
{"BoundingBox": 
{"Width":0.1468130648136139},"Confidence":63.32168960571289}],"Parents": 
[{"Name":"Vehicle"},{"Name":"Transportation"}]}, 
{"Name":"Automobile","Confidence":97.12930297851562,"Instances": 
[],"Parents":[{"Name":"Vehicle"},{"Name":"Transportation"}]}, 
{"Name":"Person","Confidence":85.63351440429688,"Instances": 
[{"BoundingBox": 
{"Width":0.024131836369633675},"Confidence":85.63351440429688}],"Parents": 
[]},{"Name":"Freeway","Confidence":55.29652786254883,"Instances": 
[],"Parents":[{"Name":"Road"}]}

# convert into JSON:
y = json.dumps(x)

print ('### Searching for people ###')

# Search for People
for p in x:
    if p['Name'] == 'Person':
        people_conf = (p['Confidence'])
        people_inst = (p['Instances'])
        people_count= len(people_inst)

print ('### Searching for cars ###')

# Search for Cars
for c in x:
    if c['Name'] == 'Car':
        car_conf = (c['Confidence'])
        car_inst = (c['Instances'])
        car_count=len(car_inst)
   
#### Data from searches ####

print ('### Data from searches ###')

#### Grade People Count ####

print ('### Start Grading ###')

if (people_conf > 84 and people_count >= 100):
    peopleScore = 'crowded'
elif (people_conf > 84 and people_count >= 50):
    peopleScore = 'manageable'
elif (people_conf > 84 and people_count >= 1):
    peopleScore = 'empty'
else:
    peopleScore = 'unknown'

#### Grade Car Count ####

if (car_conf >= 97 and car_count >= 100):
   carScore = 'crowded'
elif (car_conf >= 97 and car_count >= 3):
   carScore = 'manageable'
elif (car_conf >= 97 and car_count >= 1):
   carScore = 'empty'
else:
   carScore = 'unknown'

#### Print Grading ####

print ("People =:",peopleScore)
print ("Cars =:",carScore)
```

Here is the output from the script

```
C:\Users\mcronin02\Desktop>python project-python-final1.py
### Raw JSON file from analysis ###
### JSON file with outer label removed ###
### Searching for people ###
### Searching for cars ###
### Data from searches ###
85.63351440429688
[{'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.024131836369633675}, 'Confidence': 
85.63351440429688}]
1
97.12930297851562
[{'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.3040655553340912}, 'Confidence': 
97.12930297851562}, {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.21719124913215637}, 
'Confidence': 87.27943420410156}, {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 
0.1468130648136139}, 'Confidence': 63.32168960571289}]
3
### Start Grading ###
People =: empty
Cars =: manageable
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final version

```
# Project to take JSON response from AWS Rekognition and then People and Car 
count v1.0 7/11/2022 
import json
# Create Variables
people_confidence = (0)
people_instance = (0)
people_count = (0)
car_confidence = (0)
car_instance = (0)
car_count = (0)
# Import Data from Analysis service
raw_data = open('json1.json')
data = json.load(raw_data)
# Strip off outer Label
filtered_data = (data["Labels"])
# Search for People
for people in filtered_data:
   if people['Name'] == 'Person':
       people_confidence = (people['Confidence'])
       people_instance = (people['Instances'])
       people_count= len(people_instance)
# Search for Cars
for car in filtered_data:
    if car['Name'] == 'Car':
       car_confidence = (car['Confidence'])
       car_instance = (car['Instances'])
       car_count=len(car_instance)       
# Grade People Count
if (people_confidence > 95 and people_count >= 100):
   people_score = 'crowded'
elif (people_confidence > 95 and people_count >= 10):
   people_score = 'manageable'
elif (people_confidence > 95 and people_count >= 1):
   people_score = 'empty'
else:
  people_score = 'unknown'
# Grade Car Count
if (car_confidence >= 95 and car_count >= 100):
   car_score = 'crowded'
elif (car_confidence >= 95 and car_count >= 3):
   car_score = 'manageable'
elif (car_confidence >= 95 and car_count >= 1):
   car_score = 'empty'
else:
   car_score = 'unknown'
# Print Grading 
print ("People =:",people_score)
print ("Cars =:",car_score)
```